# Android gradle pulling files to assets

Tags: android, gradle, apk, assets

Android: I have some files shared by other projects, and like them packaged under assets/.

```
/android/app/src/main/assets/a.xml
/projects/shared/b.xml
```

how to put both a.xml and b.xml under assets/ in apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add arbitrary directories to the locations that Gradle (and the Android Plugin for Gradle) looks for assets.

For example, when [testing migrations in Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#db-migration-testing), we use this to get our Room-generated historical schemas added to our instrumentation test's assets:

```
sourceSets {
  androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
}
```

Here, we are saying that we want to add a new directory to the set of directories that populate the assets for the `androidTest` source set.

Similarly, you could do something like:

```
sourceSets {
  main.assets.srcDirs += ...
}
```

where you would have to figure out the appropriate `...` to point Gradle to wherever your other files are.

Note that the `sourceSets` closure goes inside the `android` closure of your module's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Does it support include/exclude/filter of gradle copySpec? I need to include some (not all) files under the shared directory, and need to apply filter to replace variables in the files. Thanks.

Comment: @Sunnyday: "Does it support include/exclude/filter of gradle copySpec?" -- I suspect that it does not, but I do not know for certain.

Comment: It seems android gradle plugin is not flexible as gradle itself.